# Android - onRequestPermissionsResult() is deprecated. Are there any alternatives?

Tags: java, android, permissions, request, deprecated

I tried to implement request permissions for writing and reading from storage. Everything worked good but today Android showed me that the method onRequestPermissionsResult(...) is deprecated. There are so many questions about this topic in StackOverflow, but unfortunately, they are outdated.

I called the methods below in a fragment.

It was suggested simply to call:

```
requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
StorageKeys.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
```

instead of my approach:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
StorageKeys.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE))
```

But both of them show that onRequestPermissionsResult(...) is deprecated.

Here is my onRequestPermissionsResult(...)-method:

```
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                         @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == StorageKeys.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

      if (grantResults.length > 0
          && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        exportBibTex.createBibFile();
        exportBibTex.writeBibFile(exportBibTex
            .getBibDataLibrary(libraryModel, bookDao, noteDao));

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
            getString(R.string.exported_file_stored_in) + '\n'
                + File.separator + StorageKeys.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER + File.separator + fileName
                + StorageKeys.BIB_FILE_TYPE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.storage_permission_denied,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a simple alert dialog, in which I call the onRequestPermissionsResult(...):

```
  private void showRequestPermissionDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder reqAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    reqAlertDialog.setTitle(R.string.storage_permission_needed);
    reqAlertDialog.setMessage(R.string.storage_permission_alert_msg);

    reqAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
        (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            StorageKeys.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE));
    reqAlertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
        (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

    reqAlertDialog.create().show();
  }
```

Is there any alternative for onRequestPermissionsResult(...), that I can use?

Comment: `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is not deprecated in `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`. did you use which Activity class?

Comment: I use it in a fragment. The explanation from Android Studio is: "Overrides deprecated method in 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' "

Comment: I posted answer and promote your question. so you can check my answer.

Comment: You should check out this official guide: https://youtu.be/oP-zXjkT0C0. `onActivityResult()` and `onRequestPermissionResult()` are all deprecated now.

Comment: requestPermissions method is deprecated.

Answer (score 107):

The `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method is deprecated in `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

So you may use `registerForActivityResult()` method instead of `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

You can refer this [URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).

Following is Kotlin code, but you can refer it:

```
val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // PERMISSION GRANTED
    } else {
        // PERMISSION NOT GRANTED
    }
}

// Ex. Launching ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
private fun startLocationPermissionRequest() {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
}
```

I added java code from following URL.
[How to get a permission request in new ActivityResult API (1.3.0-alpha05)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202471/how-to-get-a-permission-request-in-new-activityresult-api-1-3-0-alpha05)

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                // PERMISSION GRANTED
            } else {
                // PERMISSION NOT GRANTED
            }
        }
    }
);

// Ex. Launch the permission window -- this is in onCreateView()
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);    
    }
});
```

You can also request multiple permissions:

```
val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { permissions ->
    permissions.entries.forEach {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
    }
}

requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, can I use the ActivityResultLauncher(..) for multiple permissions? For example 
      requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
          Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
      requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

Comment: yes, you can use it. but you need to change some part of my code. i updated my post.

Comment: So you need to use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()` when call `registerForActivityResult()` method.

Comment: This is also specifically mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code).

Comment: This answer is displaying an error:
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public operator fun <T, R> DeepRecursiveFunction<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)>.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin

Comment: How to run code after permission has been granted?  Is there any existing way to pass a this code as lambda function to permission launcher?

Comment: @Gleichmut In the sniptes above, you can put the code you want to run in the `// PERMISSION GRANTED` comment, but you can't pass a lambda to the launcher. If you are having problems regarding running a code that requires some data that you had when you called `launch` on your `requestPermissionLauncher`, you will have to  savew this that somewhere (e.g. store it in a global variable) or use some other custom implementation

Comment: When dialog is declined several times, the code does not work. The `onActivityResult` method is called being called with the result `attribute` being false, but without the permission dialog being displayed.

Answer (score 39):

A simple way in **Kotlin**

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    val TAG: String = MyFragment::class.java.simpleName
    var PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
}

private val permReqLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        val granted = permissions.entries.all {
            it.value == true
        }
        if (granted) {
            displayCameraFragment()
        }
    }

private fun takePhoto() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        displayCameraFragment()
        return
    }
    activity?.let {
        if (hasPermissions(activity as Context, PERMISSIONS)) {
            displayCameraFragment()
        } else {
            permReqLauncher.launch(
                PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
    }
}

// util method
private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, permissions: Array<String>): Boolean = permissions.all {
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun displayCameraFragment() {
    // open camera fragment
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternative registerForActivityResult

Example use:

```
 private fun permissionSetup() {
    val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        requireContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsResultCallback.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    } else {
        println("Permission isGranted")
    }
}

private val permissionsResultCallback = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){
    when (it) {
        true -> { println("Permission has been granted by user") }
        false -> {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Register the permissions callback in your activity or fragment. which handle user permission
Example-Storage permission

```
 private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
        result -> {
            if (result) {
                  //Permission granted
 
            } else {
               //permission denied
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    //show permission snackbar
                } else {
                   //display error dialog
                }
            }

        });
```

Ask for the permission.The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                } else {
                    //Permission already granted 
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we need to take some permissions like audio and camera. Then we can put it on a variable of array.

```
  private val REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS =
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
```

This `registerForActivityResult` invoke when we launch with multiple permission array.

```
private val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { permissions ->
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
            if (!it.value){
                return@registerForActivityResult
            }
        }
        init()
    }
```

Now we make a function to check permission is already granted or not.

```
   private fun checkSelfPermission(): Boolean {
        return !(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0]
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1]
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    }
```

Now we check permission is granted or not from `onCreate` method. If permission is not granted then we invoke `requestMultiplePermissions.launch(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS)` like

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!checkSelfPermission()) {
            requestMultiplePermissions.launch(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - (kotlin):

```
private fun checkPermissions() {
    if (mContext?.let {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            it,
            READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Request Permissions")
    requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
        arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
 } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission Already Granted")
    }
}

private val requestMultiplePermissions =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.d(TAG, "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
        }
        if (permissions[READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] == true && permissions[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] == true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission not granted")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers address the OP requirement. But I have found few things that are missing so I thought to provide a complete example (in Koltin)

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment(){

private lateinit var permissionRequest : ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

companion object {
      
    val LOCATION_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
    }

    private fun getGpsLocation() {
        if(activity != null){
            permissionRequest.launch(LOCATION_PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.locBtn.setOnClickListener { getGpsLocation() }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        registerPermissionRequest()
    }
        
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
       
        return binding.root
    }
    
    private fun registerPermissionRequest(){
            var permissionCount = 0
            permissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
                permissions.entries.forEach {
                    if(it.value){
                        permissionCount++
                    }
    
                }
    
                if(permissionCount == 2){
                    getMyLocation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The things that are missing are

**A)Fragments must call registerForActivityResult() before they are created (i.e. initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()). Other wise it won't work and the app would crash.**

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ProfileFragment{bf12414} (210ad5a1-3286-4586-a48f-deac1d8e3eef
> id=0x7f09008b) is attempting to registerForActivityResult after being
> created. Fragments must call registerForActivityResult() before they
> are created (i.e. initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()).

B) It is recommended to request permission when it is really needed.  In my example when user clicks on `Button` with id `locBtn`, permission dialog is shown rather than showing when activity/fragment is created.

Comment: In your case you call `registerForActivityResult` in `onCreateView`. In my experience it is usually enough to create `permissionRequest` variable in `onCreate`, `onAttach` or as a initialized local variable. In `onCreate` we should check an order of calls. It would be better to create the variable before other operators, because sometimes it can be called too early.

Comment: @CoolMind, I totally agree with you. I did mention the same in the description. I have corrected that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Review the following, which can be found in the documentation.

```
// Register the permissions callback, which handles the user's response to the
// system permissions dialog. Save the return value, an instance of
// ActivityResultLauncher. You can use either a val, as shown in this snippet,
// or a lateinit var in your onAttach() or onCreate() method.
val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    }
```

After which, launch the request

```
when {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            CONTEXT,
            Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
        // You can use the API that requires the permission.
    }
    //Is not needed for it to work, but is a good practice as it plays a role
    //in letting user know why the permission is needed.
    shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...) -> {
        // In an educational UI, explain to the user why your app requires this
        // permission for a specific feature to behave as expected. In this UI,
        // include a "cancel" or "no thanks" button that allows the user to
        // continue using your app without granting the permission.
        showInContextUI(...)
    }
    else -> {
        // You can directly ask for the permission.
        // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some external library for permission handling to reduce some boilerplate code. I use [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter). [Rx Permissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is also good choice if you are using RxJava2.

Answer (score -2):

Try this in in your pubspec.yamal under flutter section:

```
 plugin:
    androidPackage: com.ly.permission
    pluginClass: PermissionPlugin
```

It works with me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does andriod studio and flutter use same libraries?