# Android studio request permissions code is wrong pls hlp

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I am working with the Kotlin language in android studio. I am requesting permission to access the gallery and I am writing this when I use the "if-else" structure to query the permission and there is a dash above the requestPermissions statement. how do we solve this.

[image]

```
activity?.let {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity().applicationContext,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
```

Comment: Did you [read the requesting permission guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code)?

Comment: I could not do it

Comment: When a method name has a line through it like that, it means the method is deprecated. Technically it will still work, but you should use the newer approach. Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551781/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-is-deprecated-are-there-any-alternatives)

Comment: It's a feature of the IDE to tell you that the function is deprecated. Figure out the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new approach to request permissions is to use launchers. You have to create the launchers before setContent().

At the very top before onCreate, create a launcher property:

```
val storagePermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.startActivityForResult())
{ result->
  if(result.RESULT_CODE == RESULT_OK) {
    //permission granted
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

When you have to do something that requires a permission. You have to check if you have the permission:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
  //you have the permission
  doSomething()
}else{
//You don't have the permission, ask for it.
  storagePermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was very immature at that time. I forgot to add permissions to androidmanifest.. but this is how you learn it..