# Waiting for the user to answer a permission request

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm working on an android project that requires location permission. I followed the documentation and everything works fine for the permission itself. But my app heavily depends on that permission so nothing will work if not granted. anyway, my problem is that I have a function that requests the permission as follows (knowing that the function `hasPermission()` just checks if permission was granted before or not):

```
public void requestPermission() {
    if(!hasPermission()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I handled my `onRequestPermissionsResult` as follows :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and my `onCreate()` is :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestPermission();
    Toast.makeText(this, "In main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How can I make the Toast in my `onCreate()` method wait until the user finishes from choosing from the permission dialog box, because if I directly try to use my `hasPermission()` function it will check even before the user chooses?

------------------------Edit----------------------------------

the `onRequestPermissionsResult` is deprecated so i used this :

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> permission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
    if(result){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and my `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    permission.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    Toast.makeText(this, "In main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and still the toast after `permission. launch()` ran before completing the permission dialog box.

Comment: `onRequestPermissionsResult` is deprecated; please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551781/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-is-deprecated-are-there-any-alternatives)

Comment: @Zain i just implemented it and still the toast under my permission.launch() ran before completing it

Comment: @moustafa Try Dexter library its best for permission handler !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i make the Toast in my onCreate() method wait until the user finish from choosing from the permission dialog box

This is normal because requesting the permission takes some time to check if the system already granted this permission to my app or not. And this is done asynchronously; so the `onCreate()` will go ahead and continue executing by showing the Toast and returning.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't seize the main thread in Android to avoid Application Not Responding (ANR); so, pausing the `onCreate()` until it checks there is a granted permission or not will cause ANR.

> until the user finish from choosing

How could we know that the user will immediately choose an option or waits one hour later on?

So, the right way to do this is in the `ActivityResultLauncher` callback which waits for the user reaction asynchronously:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> permission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
    if(result){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // The permission dialog gone; show the Toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "In main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Or probably you can fire another listener callback or update a `LiveData` object. But all this will also go in the `ActivityResultLauncher` callback.

Comment: its my first time using callbacks so sorry for asking how can i make it wait for the user reaction asynchronously

Comment: @moustafa you don't have to do much as the `ActivityResultLauncher` handles that for you using its callback in the second argument of the `registerForActivityResult`.. This callback get triggered asynchronously whenever the user closes the permission dialog. So, you can just show the Toast there

Comment: i cant get my head over it. like after i get my permission granted i want to show another dialog box for some other thing and then goes the actual code of the app. If i understood it correctly i should do it all in the callback ?

Comment: Yes that's right, within the grating `if(result)` branch you can do whatever you want.

Comment: okay and i can update the UI and all right ? like switching fragments and all ?

Comment: Absolutely; why not? Did you find obstacles on it?

Comment: no i just tried it and worked out fine thank alot for the help