# Android - Runtime permission not displaying dialog after user denies it a couple of times

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-permissions, native-android

Permissions has changed a lot on Android and the most useful implementation for me, so far has being posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551781/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-is-deprecated-are-there-any-alternatives), which uses the `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()` object and the `registerForActivityResult()` method.

---

The code from the link above was implemented in a `Fragment` as follow:

```
private lateinit var requestPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(contract) { granted ->
        if (granted) {
            // PERMISSION GRANTED CODE
        } else {
            // PERMISSION DENIED CODE
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

```
val permissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
if (permissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // PERMISSION GRANTED CODE
} else {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
}
```

---

Everything is working fine, accept on a scenario where the user declines the runtime permission notification a couple of times. In this scenario, the notification it's not being showed again and I can't figure out what is missing.

Comment: Nothing is missing, insofar as this is expected behavior: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=en#handle-denial

Comment: Intended - permission dialog used to have a checkbox with "don't ask again" option during successive requests, but design changed a couple of versions ago and now it's implied user never wants to see same request again after second denial.

Comment: And how the fork do I work around this? If he denies once, I store this and redirect the user to the app settings? Because, if that's the workaround, I'll have to store it in a database (because using things like Shared Preferences or Data Store can allow the user to delete this clearing the app cache) . But, is it right?